# Permission Denied (public key) amazon ec2 instance

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

The key from the authorized keys file inside the instance at path (`.ssh/authorized_keys`) got deleted accidentally. As I know, that key is same to the `pem` file which is used for `ssh`. And now, I am not able to ssh into the instance using that `pem` file, Is there any way to `ssh` to that instance?

Comment: So there's no key in your `authorized_keys` file anymore? Is there any other account on the server?

Comment: This would be better on serverfault.com

Comment: I wonder if this link is helpful... http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#how-to-generate-your-own-key-and-import-it-to-aws  I'd suggest either re-creating the key pair or extracting the public key from your existing pem file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an Amazon EC2 instance is launched, the public half of a nominated Public/Private keypair is copied to `.ssh/authorized_keys`. You can then login to the instance using the private half of the keypair.

If the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file has been deleted, then it is not possible to login to the instance using that keypair. If another keypair has been installed on the system (for the same or a different user), login to the instance using that user & keypair.

Worst case, if there are no available keypairs, you could mount the volume on another instance and affect a repair. It would involve:

- **On the 'unhappy' instance:**

  - Stop the instance
  - Detach the root volume (let's call it Volume A) -- be sure to remember the device identifier, eg `/dev/sda1`
- **Launch a new instance:**

  - Attach Volume A
  - Login to the new instance
  - Navigate to Volume A and replace the `authorized_keys` file (can be a new key)
  - Stop the new instance
  - Detach Volume A
- **On the 'unhappy instance':**

  - Reattach Volume A (keeping the same device name)
  - Boot it up!